# Borrowed value does not live long enough with Vec of Cow

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here is a minimalist example of a problem I'm encountering. The following code produces the below error. I just encountered this Cow thing and I don't know how it works exactly. How should I fix this?

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Error> = Vec::new();
    {
        let e = Error { value: None };
        let value = "bar".to_string();
        let error = e.with_value(&value);
        v.push(error);
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

// Code below here is in crate I cannot change.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Error<'v> {
    pub value: Option<Cow<'v, str>>
}

impl<'v> Error<'v> {
    pub fn with_value(mut self, value: &'v str) -> Self {
        self.set_value(value);
        self
    }
    
    pub fn set_value(&mut self, value: &'v str) {
        if self.value.is_none() {
            self.value = Some(value.into());
        }
    }
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `value` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:34
   |
8  |         let error = e.with_value(&value);
   |                                  ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |         v.push(error);
10 |     }
   |     - `value` dropped here while still borrowed
11 |     println!("{:?}", v);
   |                      - borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're creating a separate scope with the `{ ... }`?  That's causing the `String` to drop while a reference to it is in the `Vec` which fails to compile.

Comment: If you really want to use `Cow`, then the `Cow` has to outlive the `&str` it borrows (in this case the `value` has to outlive `v`). In your code the `value` is dropped before being accessed via `v`, which is why you get the error.

Comment: Oh so you guys are saying that Cow does not make a copy?

Comment: `Cow` stands for copy-on-write. It only copies the underlying data when needed (i.e. when a write is to be performed), which is why it holds the borrow. [See the documentation of `std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). If you want to make a clone of the string into your `Error` type, simply use `pub value: Option<String>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a scope, when that scope exits your String is freed, hence the reference is invalid.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Error> = Vec::new();
    
    let e = Error { value: None };
    let value = "bar".to_string();
    let error = e.with_value(&value);
    v.push(error);
    
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1921397e854a40ca0e76f6cff7431e2b)

`Cow` can take references, but they need to be valid still. You can make it owned:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Error> = Vec::new();
    
        let e = Error { value: None };
        let value = "bar".to_string();
        let error = e.with_owned_value(value);
        v.push(error);
    
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

// Code below here is in crate I cannot change.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Error<'v> {
    pub value: Option<Cow<'v, str>>
}

impl<'v> Error<'v> {
    pub fn with_value(mut self, value: &'v str) -> Self {
        self.set_value(value);
        self
    }
    
    pub fn set_value(&mut self, value: &'v str) {
        if self.value.is_none() {
            self.value = Some(value.into());
        }
    }
    
    pub fn with_owned_value(self, value: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            value: Some(value.into())
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0246da5b94e2eba844f801867aa49277)

Answer (score 1):

this code doesn't compile because Error contains a reference to value, but value is destroyed when scope exits, but Error continues to live